# How do you show content before a request is finished with React?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am creating a website using *ReactJS* and would like content to look like it does below while the page is getting data from my endpoint (eg. slow connections). I am looking for a solution that can be easily implemented to elements such as `p` while they are loading data.

[image: Screenshot of purgecss.com]

How would I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably would create an component that would look like the screenshot that you provided in the question or an image that looks like that whichever you prefer. And do something like this.

```
state = {
  isFetching: true,
  data: {},
  isError: false
}

componentDidMount() {
  //doing the fetch
  fetch('api').then(
    response => {
       this.setState({ data: response.json(), isFetching: false });//finish with fetch
    },
    error => {
       this.setState({ isError: true, isFetching: false });//finish with fetch but error
    }
  );
}

render() {
  if(this.state.isFetching)
    return <CustomLoadingComponent />;


  return(
    <div>
      whatever you wanna show!
    </div>
  )
}
```

So, if it's fetching then load the custom loading component, when data returns do whatever you wanna do.

Comment: This appears to be best written and closest to what I am looking for issue, thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of handling this (I believe it's called 'lazy loading').

Here's one way.

Assuming you are using a Promise based method of loading data from your API, I would:

1. In your component constructor, set `this.state = { loading: true }`.
2. Declare and initialize two style objects: `const normalStyles = {}` , `const greyStyles={}` with your choice of CSS keys/values.
3. In each `<p>` or whichever elements you would like to change, add a `style` prop, for example `style={this.state.loading ? greyStyles : normalStyles}`.
4. When your promise resolves, call `this.setState({loading: false})`.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do it myself I would create two components
- one "real" component, and second that will serve as a placeholder for future content:

```
//this component is like a loader, it will display silver square blocks in place of content that is not yet present.
const SectionPlaceholder = () => (
  <section>
   <span className="avatar-placeholder" />
   <span className="gray-bar" />
   <span className="gray-bar" />
  </section>
)

//this components is a "real" component that will render data when they're available
const Section = (props) => (
  <section>
    <img src={props.user.image} />
    <p>{props.user.username}</p>
    <p>{props.user.user_email}</p> 
  </section>
)
```

Now having these two components and knowing that data will be available at some point in the future we can simply show placeholders until data is fetched:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.userData ?
        <Section user={this.props.userData} />
        :
        <SectionPlaceholder />
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

This should give you desired effect.